# Limelight Video Player || How to play HTML5 video with it

Tags: javascript, html, flash, video, aem

Currently, I am facing issue with Limelight player. It is playing flash videos with Limelight player and player ID is the argument which is passed for the flash videos.

Flash player videos are causing issue and we need to change the approach to play HTML5 videos instead of flash player.But I can't see or find any relevant code in which video stream from limelight player can be feed into the HTML5 player.

Any suggestions or code snippets for making Limelight videos being played with the HTML5 player will be very helpful.

Regards

Comment: How is this issue related to AEM? Asking since you used the tag.

Comment: I am using Lime light component in AEM , so it's related

Comment: Can you add the information for this limelight video player from AEM? I don't think this is an OOTB component.

Comment: Sure, we have a custom component in AEM, which shows video hosted in limelight account on basis of player id.   https://support.limelight.com/public/video/en/Default.htm

Answer (score 3):

I am currently working on it and its bit of complex but here is what limelight came with :

```
   <div id="limelight_player_659410"></div><script src="//video.limelight.com/player/limelightjs-player.js"></script>
<script>LimelightPlayerUtil.embed({"height":321,"playerId":"limelight_player_659410","width":480,"mediaId":"c3713feac461425e8889d55689358352","playerForm":"Player"});</script>
```

**First approach** is to create limelight callback function:

```
function limelightPlayerCallback(playerId, eventName, data) {
   console.dir(data); 
   colsole.log(data.thumbnailUrl);
   console.log(data.title);
   console.log(data.description);

}
```

So when you call : 
LimelightPlayerUtil.embed({"width":"480px","height":"300px", "playerId":"HEREisYOURcontainerID", "mediaId":"HEREisYOURmediaId", "playerForm":"Player"});

your limelightPlayerCallback will get "data".

Now you can see in console all data.proprties and use which one you want to manipulate HTML5 Video tag and display data.

**Second approach**: Not sure if this link is valid by limelight but I was able to get it from calls I was making :

https://production-ps.lvp.llnw.net/r/PlaylistService/media/d7d5b0ec19e1441781c3df4209fe5cb6/getMobilePlaylistByMediaId

This link will return JSON with all properties. Please note that "d7d5b0ec19e1441781c3df4209fe5cb6" is video ID so replace and use any of your video IDs. Once you get JSON you will get URL and you can inject HTML5 video tag :)